# phpMyAdmin forcing database upgrade

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have Linux cPanel VPS server and it is running fine. My PHPMyAdmin was working fine. All of sudden, it is throwing following error message:

phpMyAdmin - Error
You should upgrade to MySQL 5.5.0 or later

If I upgrade MySQL database server then it may cause problem on all hosted databases. Is there any solution work around to use phpMyAdmin rather than going to upgrade MySQL server?

Thanks,

Comment: try to export a backup file first !! and then do the upgrade (it is very important for security reasons) ,, so after you can import all your data and get to work again

Comment: Currently, we have installed MySQL 5.2 and upgrade to 5.5, will create any problem with backup export/import database on server?

All databases will work without any problem?

Comment: No it will have no impact on it !! just one thing on the import you'll have a max file size to uplaod , verify that your file doesn't exceed it .

Comment: Ok..I will try that out..

Comment: I have upgraded database version successfully. I have encountered only password problem for already created database users. I have reset the password which has fixed the problem.

Thanks.